# Raspberry Pi 2 B Network problem

Tags: pi-2, networking, wifi, wireless, internet

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 B, and I'm trying to connect to the wireless network "MiuFurinji". I hovered my mouse on the network icon on the top-right corner, and it showed the following code(I already entered the password to the network and connected):

```
wlan0:Associated with MiuFurinji
wlan0:Configured 192.168.0.107/24
eth0:Link is down
```

Typing in an ifstatus command shows the following:

```
wlan0: link beat detected
lo: link beat detected
eth0: unplugged
```

An ifconfig command shows the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:71:36:34  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:14612 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14612 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1186716 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:1186716 (1.1 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:60:06:02:33  
          inet addr:192.168.0.107  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11661 errors:0 dropped:5212 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1794278 (1.7 MiB)  TX bytes:63034 (61.5 KiB)
```

This is my /etc/networks/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

However, when I open an internet browser, the message "Problem Loading Page: Server not found" is shown. How can I fix this so that I can access the internet?

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. I'm an extreme beginner, so try to keep it simple.

Comment: Paste the output of `ip route` into your question. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
which has some detail, and the correct interfaces. What you have posted seems OK, although one can never be sure when the files seem to have been modified.

Comment: I think I solved it. What I forgot was to reboot the pi. Sorry for the inconvenience. :(